# Why won't my variables add up?

Tags: javascript, calculator, html

EDIT : **I managed to solve the problem. Here's the new code :**

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


function get(){};
function add(){
var ff= Number(document.getElementById("fn").value);
var ll= Number(document.getElementById("ln").value);
var gg= ff + ll

document.getElementById("fn").value = "";
document.getElementById("ln").value = "";
document.getElementById("rslt").value = gg};
</script>
<h1>Calculator</h1>


<article id="a1">
<input id="fn" type="number" placeholder="first number" style="display:inline">

<span id="mark">MARK</span>

<input id="ln" type="number" placeholder="last number" style="display:inline">

<span>=</span>

<input id="rslt" type="number" placeholder="result" style="display:inline">

<button type="button" onclick="add();"> + </button>
<button type="button"> - </button>
<button type="button"> X </button>
<button type="button"> % </button>
</article>

<p id="hint">This is a paragraph.</p>



</body>
```

**PS : Thanks for all the answers and comments.**

> I don't know why my variables "ff" and "ll" won't add up in this page?
>   What's the problem? I am attempting to create something of a
>   calculator and is currently programming the ADD function. But when I
>   enter numbers in both fields and press ADD it doesn't add correctly. I
>   tried the same method alone without all the other code and it worked.
>
> Here's all of the page code in case I fail to include the part where
>   the problem lies:
>
> ```
>  <!DOCTYPE html>
>     <html>
>     <head>
>  </head>
>     <body>
>
>     <article>
>     <h1>Calculator</h1>
>     <input id="fn" type="real" placeholder="first number"></input> 
>     <span id="mark"> + </span>
>     <input id="ln" type="real" placeholder="last number"></input>
>     <span id="e"> = </span>
>     <input id="re" type="real" value="0" placeholder="result"></input>
>     <br /> <br />
>     <table>
>     <th><button type=button onclick="add()">add +</button></th>
>     <th><button type=button onclick="subtract()">subtract -</button></th>
>     <th><button type=button onclick="devide()">devide %</button></th>
>     <th><button type=button onclick="multiply()">multiply *</button></th>
>     <th><button type=button onclick="clea()">clear</button></th>
>
>
>     </article>
>
>
>     <script>
>     //setting up variables
>     var cc="+"
>     //setting up functions
>
>     //get function
>     function get(){
>     var ff=document.getElementById("fn").value
>     var ll= document.getElementById("ln").value
>     }
>     //add function
>     function add() {get();cc="+";
>     if (cc=="+"){
>     document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "ADD";
>
>     document.getElementById("re").value =ff+ll;
>     alert(ff)
>     }} 
>     //subtract function
>     function subtract() {get(); cc="-"
>     if (cc=="-"){document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "SUBTRACT"}
>     }
>     //devide function
>     function devide() {get();cc="%"
>     if (cc=="%"){document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "DEVIDE"}
>     }
>     //multiply function
>     function multiply() {get();cc="*"
>     if (cc=="*"){
>     document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "MULTIPLY"}
>     }
>     //clear function 
>     function clea() {
>     document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "CLEAR"
>     document.getElementById("re").value =""}
>     </script>
>
>     <p id="hint" style="background-color:yellow; display:inline"></p>
>     </body>
>     </html>
> ```

Comment: You're alerting `ff` when that variable is in a completely different scope.

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues I see here:

1) The variables you create in `get()` are only accessible within the scope of that function. If you want to see the results within the other functions, you have to declare them first outside of the `get` function:

```
//setting up variables
var cc="+";
var ll;
var ff;
//setting up functions

function add() {get();cc="+";
    if (cc=="+"){
    document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "ADD";

    document.getElementById("re").value ="";
    alert(ff)
}}
```

2) You're not actually adding or subtracting anywhere that I see in your code. You're simply clearing the value of the `re` element (`document.getElementById("re").value ="";`) and then alerting the value placed into the `ff` element (`alert(ff)`)

Comment: I think you're wrong. I tried the code in another answer omitting the ll an ff declarations. It worked, suggesting that the problem lies elsewhere. And yeah, I wasn't adding anything when I inserted the code to my post. Stupid me forgot to restore the original code before posting.

Comment: I'm not wrong. Variables are hoisted in scope until they find where the variable was first declared, until they hit the top level (window) and become global. This is extremely elementary JavaScript functionality.

Comment: @oss-solomon I see. But it doesn't make sense in this context. I didn't declare my variables before giving them their value in the function, and it worked with no problems. Can you explain why's that? Is it because of the function being called through a button? because the entire page is loaded before you click a button and by that time the variable already has a value.

Answer (score 0):

`"real"` is not a valid `type` for `<input>` element, which is also self-closing `</input>` is invalid HTML; set `type` to `"number"` and use `.valueAsNumber` to get value of `as` number instead of a string.

Include missing closing `</table>` tag at HTML.

`ff` and `ll` are local variables in `get` function. Set the variables as global variables for each function to have access to the values.

You can also set `#mark` `.textContent` to the current mathematical operation within the respective function calls.

JavaScript at Question does not actually perform any mathematical calculations.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <input id="fn" type="number" placeholder="first number">
    <span id="mark"> + </span>
    <input id="ln" type="number" placeholder="last number">
    <span id="e"> = </span>
    <input id="re" type="number" value="0" placeholder="result">
    <br /> <br />
    <table>
      <th><button type=button onclick="add()">add +</button></th>
      <th><button type=button onclick="subtract()">subtract -</button></th>
      <th><button type=button onclick="devide()">devide /</button></th>
      <th><button type=button onclick="multiply()">multiply *</button></th>
      <th><button type=button onclick="clear()">clear</button></th>
    </table>
  </article>

  <p id="hint" style="background-color:yellow; display:inline"></p>
  <script>
    //setting up variables
    var cc = "+",
      ff, ll;
    //setting up functions
    var fn = document.getElementById("fn");
    var ln = document.getElementById("ln");
    var mark = document.getElementById("mark");
    var re = document.getElementById("re");
    var hint = document.getElementById("hint");

    function log() {
      console.log(re.value);
    }
    //get function
    function get() {
      ff = fn.valueAsNumber;
      ll = ln.valueAsNumber;
    }
    //add function
    function add() {
      get();
      cc = "+";
      hint.innerHTML = "ADD";
      mark.textContent = " " + cc + " ";
      // do the math here
      re.value = ff + ll;
      log();
    }
    //subtract function
    function subtract() {
      get();
      cc = "-";
      hint.innerHTML = "SUBTRACT";
      mark.textContent = " " + cc + " ";
      re.value = ff - ll;
      log();
    }
    //devide function
    function devide() {
      get();
      cc = "/";
      hint.innerHTML = "DEVIDE";
      mark.textContent = " " + cc + " ";
      re.value = ff / ll;
      log();
    }
    //multiply function
    function multiply() {
      get();
      cc = "*"
      hint.innerHTML = "MULTIPLY";
      mark.textContent = " " + cc + " ";
      re.value = ff * ll;
      log();
    }
    //clear function 
    function clear() {
      hint.innerHTML = "CLEAR"
      re.value = fn.value = ln.value = "";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What I'm saying is that document.getElementById("re").value =ff+ll doesn't work in this code. I changed that later to ="" just to see if the calculation or the value editing didn't work.

Comment: @Itameio What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The correct result is returned here, as long as `get()` is called first

Comment: @Itameio Can you describe what "doesn't work" at code at stacksnippets?

Comment: I'm talking about my own code. Variables suppsedly can be added to each in a simple line like ff+ll right? Well when trying that alone it works. But in the code I posted it doesn't.

Comment: No, you are concatenating strings, not numbers at code at original Question, for example `"1"` + `"1"` = `"11"` where the values are strings. Use `.valueAsNumber` property to convert string `.value` to a number or use one of the approaches at other answers to convert string to a number.

Comment: Thanks. Used Number() to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that you will get a string, when you use

```
document.getElementById("fn").value
```

So, before adding the variables `ff` and `ll` make sure to convert them to float (or int). You could do something like

```
re = parseFloat(ff) + parseFloat(ll);
```

or

```
re=ff - (-ll);
```

In the second example the conversion is done implicitly, since the `-` operator requires numerical arguments. Using the `+` operator would simply concatenate the two string values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euv8hsyo/) example to fix up your add function.

```
function add() {
  var fn = document.getElementById("fn").value
  var ln = document.getElementById("ln").value
  document.getElementById("re").value = new Number(fn) + new Number(ln);
}
```

Comment: Where is issue of invalid HTML addressed at Answer? `new Number()` is not necessary

Comment: @guest271314 I created a SIMPLE example that the OP could build on top of. Yes, there were plenty of problems with OP's code (e.g., unclosed tags) and I should have mentioned them. Your example is much more complete. Regarding your `new Number()` is unnecessary assertion, if you run my code in JSFiddle without some type of number conversion you're going to get a concatenation of strings (at least I did). To make sure you're getting a number every time (because the input fields are treated as text), I'd cast them someway or another (e.g., `parseFloat` used below) since javascript is dynamic.

Comment: "SIMPLE" is relative. `<input type="number">` has a `.valueAsNumber` property

Comment: great, so you did cast it. in any case, OP needs a more through introduction to Javascript and variable scope.  OP, check out this:  https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

Comment: @user2243357 Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need

```
if (cc=="..."){
...
}
```

just write it like

```
function add() {
  get();
  cc=="..."
  document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "ADD";
  document.getElementById("re").value = ff + ll;
  mark.innerHTML = cc;
}
```

try it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>
  <article>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <input id="fn" type="number" placeholder="first number">
    <span id="mark"> + </span>
    <input id="ln" type="number" placeholder="last number">
    <span id="e"> = </span>
    <input id="re" type="number" value="0" placeholder="result">
    <br /> <br />
    <table>
      <th><button type=button onclick="add()">add +</button></th>
      <th><button type=button onclick="subtract()">subtract -</button></th>
      <th><button type=button onclick="devide()">devide /</button></th>
      <th><button type=button onclick="multiply()">multiply *</button></th>
      <th><button type=button onclick="clea()">clear</button></th>
    </table>
  </article>

  <script>
    //setting up variables
    var cc = "+", ff, ll;
    //setting up functions
    var mark = document.getElementById("mark");
    
    //get function
    function get() {
      ff = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fn").value);
      ll = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ln").value);
    }
    //add function
    function add() {
      get();
      cc = "+";
      document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "ADD";
      document.getElementById("re").value = ff + ll;
      mark.innerHTML = cc;
    }
    //subtract function
    function subtract() {
      get();
      cc = "-";
      document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "SUBTRACT";
      document.getElementById("re").value = ff - ll;
      mark.innerHTML = cc;
    }
    //devide function
    function devide() {
      get();
      cc = "/";
      document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "DEVIDE";
      document.getElementById("re").value = ff / ll;
      mark.innerHTML = cc;
    }
    //multiply function
    function multiply() {
      get();
      cc = "*";
      document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "MULTIPLY";
      document.getElementById("re").value = ff * ll;
      mark.innerHTML = cc;
    }
    //clear function 
    function clea() {
      document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "CLEAR"
      document.getElementById("re").value = ""
    }
  </script>

  <p id="hint" style="background-color:yellow; display:inline"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it different, optimize your previous answer and now it using `parseFloat` :D